# mongodump error creating directory for metadata file : Access denied

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodump

I have created a database and accompanying user for the database but It appears I cant do backups with that user and neither can I add the backup role to the user.
Having checked documentation I added a user but this time at the admin database level (`use admin`) and added backup role for the same.

However when I attempt to do a backup I am getting an error *Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file /var/backups/...: mkdir /var/backups/...: permission denied*

Steps
1.

```
 `kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it <pod_name> -- sh`
```

(mongo is running in kubernetes)

2.

```
`use admin`
```

(switch to admin user)

3.

```
db.createUser( {user: "backupuser", pwd: "abc123", roles: ["root", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase","backup"], mechanisms:["SCRAM-SHA-256"]})
```

4. 

```
 `db.getUsers({ filter: { mechanisms: "SCRAM-SHA-256" } })`
```

(Verify if user exists)

5.

```
 mongodump -u backupuser -p abc123 --authenticationDatabase admin -d TESTDB --out /var/backups/dump-25-05-22 --gzip
```

Is it possible to even amend permissions for this user in such a case or I should be looking somewhere else.
In the container it seems I cant do any permission updates (for the group) but the user already has all permissions on /var/backups :

```
ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 18  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb 18  2021 ..
```

I am not convinced either that I should be going even this far. The backup should execute out of the box as per the user I added.

What exactly am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to do from mongodb side. The user that is running `mongodump` command doesn't have the required permission.  To check if thats the case, you can try this out : `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/backups/` before running `mongodump`.

Comment: I cannot sudo (command not found) . Then chmod 777 -R /var/backups/ yields an error changing permissions of '/var/backups/': Operation not permitted

Comment: @Golide  This is a common error for debain. You can use https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425664 this answer to use the `sudo` command.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. If i'm applying the `mongodump ...` command as entrypoint to a mongo-container, the dump cannot be written to a mounted volume (permission denied).

If i hack into the container and run exact the same command manually, everything works.

Solution that worked for me as an entrypoint was:
Changing `mongodump ...` to `/bin/sh -c "mongodump ...`

Comment: @skymir1 I will post the recommended solution . You have to dump to the /tmp path then do whatever you want with the dump from there onwards